# How to detect which section is visible in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to detect which section is visible by using `indexPathsForVisibleRows`, like so:

```
-(BOOL)isRowZeroVisible {
    NSArray *visibleRowIndexes = [self.agendaTable indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    for (NSIndexPath *index in visibleRowIndexes) {

        NSLog(@"The visible row has an index of: %ld", (long)index.row);

        if (index.row == 0) {
            NSLog(@"index.row is indeed 0");
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

However this doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why. Is there any other way of detecting the visible section using its index?

Comment: in what way does it not work? does it not return true when it should or the other way around? the code actually looks correct at first view

Comment: Try `index.section`.

Comment: @luk2302 It doesn't NSLog anything, which tells me that the function isn't running at all, not sure why though.

Comment: have you tried adding more logs? one at the start of the method, just to check if it gets called, one after indexPatchsFor... logging the count of the returned paths to check if they might be empty, etc.

Comment: @luk2302 Yup just did, even at the start of the method before the for loop begins, it doesn't log.

Comment: @zaph Good catch, still doesn't seem to solve the overall problem though.

Comment: where are you calling the method from? since it does not get called, its actual code is really irrelevant right now^^

Comment: @luk2302 I'm calling it in `ViewController.m` right after `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Can you Show that call and in what method IT happens, etc.

Comment: Btw: does your table view actually display data?

Comment: @luk2302 show which call? Yes my tableview displays data. Everything else runs, it's just this function that won't.

Comment: Show the method from where you call isRowZeroVisible - otherwise i cant help

Comment: @luk2302 you can view the whole method here: https://gist.github.com/ghobs91/95466a8715fab771002c

Comment: YOU NEVER CALL THE FUNCTION :D sorry for shouting...

Comment: @luk2302 Oh jeez, very silly mistake. I called the function from `viewDidAppear`, and now it logs this: 
"The visible section has an index of: 0 
index.row is indeed 0"

But scrolling through the table doesn't cause it to continuosly log the visible section index, it only does it once.

Comment: of course, why should it log continiously? call the function in cellForRowAtIndexPath and you should be fine.

Comment: @luk2302 Thank you! Feel free to write that down as an answer so others can clearly see what solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that the method actually never got called you have to place its call in the right place. There are a couple of places that might be right:

- `- tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`
- `- tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`

or as I wrote in my comment: `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

The best choice probably is a combination of the two earlier methods because they will notify you if the 0-cell gets removed AND if it gets added. That would not be true for the third option.

Additionally you might want to get clear if you want to check for a section or a specific row since there is a mismatch between the text and the code.